# Hide checked cells with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to hide cells which was checked from TableView. So, I'm trying to work with numberOfRowsAtIndexPath.

Now I have something like this:

```
  let checkedPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "checked == true")
  (goals as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(checkedPredicate)
  print((goals as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(checkedPredicate).count)
```

But I have no idea how to work with NSPredicate if I need to check Boolean. I hope you'll understand me.

Comment: The content of goals array is quite unclear. Is it some sort of goal object with checked property? You can filter the array without casting to `NSArray` using swift's `filter`

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/), there's also a nice tutorial on nshipster.com about this: http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/

Comment: @libec ,thanks you, I tried filter, but if I have 3 checked cells and 2 normal - it will hide 3 cells from end of the tableView. But I need to hide certain cells